# How can I call the function in diferent block in PHP?

Tags: php, html, function, for-loop

php dummie here.
My teacher gave us this code to learn the For loop and how to use functions in PHP, when I wrote it on Sublime Text 3 it doesnt work and i dont know why, any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CICLO FOR Y FUNCTION</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Uso de funciones (function) y el ciclo FOR</h1>
    <h1>helo</h1>
    <?php
        function muestra($valor){
            if($valor<0){
                $color = "red";
                echo "<td><font color='$color'></font></td><br>\n";
            }
            else{
                $color = "blue";
                echo "<td><font color='$color'></font></td>\n";
            }
        }
    ?>
        <table border="1">
    <?php
        for($x=0; $x<=2; $x+=0.01){
            echo "<tr>";
            muestra($x);
            muestra(sin($x));
            muestra(cos($x));
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkVj4.png)

Comment: you didn't put anything between <font></font>

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `<br>` tag, it's useless here!
2. You need to display data within the cell to see a result with the color.
3. Instead of `<font color="">` you should use `<span style="color: <your color>;">`... Why? The `<font>` tag is deprecated in HTML 5 (which is indicated by the DOCTYPE)!

You code should then look like below.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CICLO FOR Y FUNCTION</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Uso de funciones (function) y el ciclo FOR</h1>
    <h1>helo</h1>
    <?php
    function muestra($valor) {
        if ($valor < 0) {
            $color = "red";
            echo "<td><span style=\"color: $color;\">{$valor}</span></td>\n";
        } else {
            $color = "blue";
            echo "<td><span style=\"color: $color;\">{$valor}</span></td>\n";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x += 0.01) {
            echo "<tr>";
            muestra($x);
            muestra(sin($x));
            muestra(cos($x));
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

A better coding style is to have only one `echo` to output your table data and use `return` inside the function instead of `echo`. To archive this and have a cleaner code you can rewrite the above example like below.

```php
<?php

function muestra($valor) {
    if ($valor < 0) {
        return '<td><span style="color: red;">' . $valor . '</span></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return '<td><span style="color: blue;">' . $valor . '</span></td>' . PHP_EOL;
}

$output = '';
for ($x = 0; $x <= 2; $x += 0.01) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $output .= muestra($x);
    $output .= muestra(sin($x));
    $output .= muestra(cos($x));
    $output .= '</tr>';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CICLO FOR Y FUNCTION</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Uso de funciones (function) y el ciclo FOR</h1>
    <h1>helo</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```